# How to Include a Node Module like bluebird in threadpool?

Tags: node.js, web-worker, node-modules

I am using worker threads. 
How to include a  node module inside thread pool environment 
can anyone please help ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads

Answer (score 0):

If you need to require native modules then you may need to use tiny-worker:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-worker

This is explained in the documentation of webworker-threads, see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads